# Typescript callbacks

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, callback

Is it possible to create callbacks in typescripts Java's way?

```
interface Callback () {
   OnSuccess()
   OnError()
}


doSomething("whatever", "we need", new Callback {
   Onsuccess(){

   }

   OnError () {

   }
})
```

or there is betters ways to get this?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Not using a class but an object literal. However in JavaScript the standard is to use a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for the kind of example you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can do something similar in typescript:

```
interface Callback {
    OnSuccess(): void
    OnError(): void
}

function doSomething(s: string, s2: string, cb: Callback) {
    if (s == s2) {
        cb.OnSuccess();
    } else {
        cb.OnError();
    }
}

doSomething("whatever", "we need", { // Object literal implementing the interface (structure determines compatibility)
    OnSuccess() {

    },
    OnError() {

    }
})
```

Comment: in the onSuccess callback I need to call a page function referring this.something() but the method is never called, do you know how can I call a method outside the callback?